# How to integrate Linkedin with my Android application?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I want to integrate linkedin with my Android app.
In this I want to do login with linkedin and to do post on my linked account.

How can I do it?

Comment: No.  Please try and ask for helep with programming problems in future - ie things you've actually tried, as per the FAQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230947/how-to-intregate-linked-in-api-to-android-application

Comment: @Poldie -  I don't see the point in being so negative.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn provides a [REST based API](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis).
you can code to that API using the [Apache HTTP Client](http://d.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

visit the LinkedIn Developers site [here](http://developer.linkedin.com)

also this might be helpful (I am not familiar with it, though):
http://code.google.com/p/jlinkedin-linkedin-java-api/